# SQL Output Inserted

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have two buttons on a page, one that logs a start time, and one that logs an end time.

The start time button performs an sql insert. 
At that point i need to grab the primary key that's create. To do this i want to use the sql command (output inserted).

Then when the stop time is clicked,the row should be update with a stop time using the primary key from the start in the where clause. 
I believe insert SQL is correct but i don't know how to pass the primary key to the next command.

Code dump, with what i have so far.

```
var command1 = "INSERT INTO [Time] ([Start Time], [Work Order]) OUTPUT INSERTED.PrimaryKey VALUES (@StartTime, @Work_Order)";
using (SqlConnection cnn1 = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(command1, cnn1))
    {
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work_Order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.CommandArgument;
        cnn1.Open();
        Label1.Text = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        cnn1.Close();
    }
}

var command = "UPDATE [Time] SET [Stop Time] = @StopTime WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @PrimaryKey";
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StopTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrimaryKey", *PrimaryKey from INSERT output*

        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are not using stored procedures?? in stored procedures you can do this easily

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrimaryKey", PrimaryKey from INSERT output
` definitely not a good approach to doing this.` create a stored procedure and learn how to use `SqlParameter` and how to use `ParameterDirection.Output` do this in a Stored Procedure with in the Stored procedure assign your OutPut Param = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS pk

Comment: I have never done a stored procedure before so i was trying different things first. I just code in my free time. Before i doing it that way i was i wanted see if there was another way i am more used to.

Comment: @Itomship Can you please mark answer so this can be referenced in similar questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of having it go to the label have it go to an int and then set the label text with the int. Then pass the int on the second part. Declare the int outside the scope of the using statements though or it will be disposed and you will get a null reference exception when you try and call it later.

Edit: To add, this would be better if you convert to stored procs and define the SqlParameter objects (you don't have them, you'll need them).

[SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    int myPK;
    var command1 = "INSERT INTO [Time] ([Start Time], [Work Order]) OUTPUT INSERTED.PrimaryKey VALUES (@StartTime, @Work_Order)";
    using (SqlConnection cnn1 = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(command1, cnn1))
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work_Order", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.CommandArgument;
            cnn1.Open();
            myPk = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
            Label1.Text = myPk.ToString();
            cnn1.Close();
        }
    }

    var command = "UPDATE [Time] SET [Stop Time] = @StopTime WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @PrimaryKey";
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StopTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrimaryKey", myPK);

            FindControl("Work_OrderLabel"); ;

            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that you are misguiding the OP after an Insert to return the newly inserted PrimaryKey he should use something like this 
`SqlParameter outputKeyId = new SqlParameter("@PrimaryKey", SqlDbType.Int);
outputKeyId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;` I would suggest creating a Stored Procedure and having one of the Params set to OutPut...

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yeah I would do the stored proc and define the directions too- but this question seemed to me to be a basic logic flow question. I also added mention to it.

Comment: `alykins` I agree the op has multiple issues going on here

Comment: As i said above i never did stored procedure work before, so i was trying out methods i am used to. Sounds like i need to do a stored procedure so i will start trying that thanks.

Comment: well there is no better time like the present to learn newer techniques.. expand your mind and try to think outside the box